# How do i format a value in Angular-formly

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I have to convert my input value from number to currency only after blur. 
But i can write it only in console.log, is it not possible to write it back in the view?

[Look at the Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxl73j)
And open the console. write any number and u see what the converter do. I need the Value in my input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create a [custom field type](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field) that uses one of the following option:

1. `ngx-currency` https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-ol5cs9
2. `ngx-mask`
3. custom directive which relies on on `ControlValueAccessor`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv7mnc

Comment: I know your answer from github, but this will not fix my problem. 
I have to write it back into the input where the User has written, not to API. 
The "ngx-mask" is a solution, but not in my project, because we create the form only through a config file, i have no access to any <input> elements, this means i could not write any attributes what the mask needs.

Comment: you can create a custom field type (https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field) that uses `ngx-mask` and be able to pass the extra options that you may you need.

Comment: Yes now i have the solution with ngx-currency together. 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-ol5cs9?file=app/formly-field-input.ts

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the below way, We can use blur event under the templateOptions

```
templateOptions: {
                                    label: 'Minimum Value',
                                    placeholder: 'Minimum Value',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    keydown: (field, $event) => {
                                        return ValidateNumericChars(field, $event);
                                    },
                                    focus: (a, event) => {
                                        event.target.value = Number(event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""));
                                    },
                                    blur: (a, event) => {
                                        event.target.value = this.utility.formatCurrency(event.target.value);
                                    }
                                },
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

```
 {
    key: 'scorePoints',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Points',
      placeholder: 'Insert Points',
      type: 'number',
      required: false,
      allowedKeys: '[0-9]',
    }
  }
```

This allows the user to enter only numbers,
although when I receive the value of the model I get it as a string, it is enough to make a casting to number..

However, if you want to recieve a number it is good to initialize the model.

Setting the object field to 0 already forces the field to be returned as numeric.

```
form = new FormGroup({});
model : MyFormInterfaceModel ={
    levelName:'Level 1',
    scorePoints:0
  };
```